# File matching pattern to exclude source code?

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am trying to configure a Build Definition in VSTS. I am currently working on a `Copy Files` task (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts) to copy the build results over to a directory of my choice. I am having trouble with finding the correct pattern to write in the "Contents" field to prevent copying c# source files (*.cs) and .pdb files.

The pattern I am currently iterating on is:

```
**
!**\*.cs
**\!*.cs
!*.cs
!**\*.pdb
**\!*.pdb
!*.pdb
```

I came to this pattern after reading https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/vsts/build-release/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=vsts and checking the default pattern for the `Visual Studio Test` task.

I would want the pattern I end up using to prevent copying those files, but at the same time allow copying Razor pages (*.cshtml).

With the pattern above, *cs and .pdb files are being copied to my target directory.

Could anyone point me to the correct pattern to use?

Edit:
Could it be that the order of lines in the pattern affect the results? Aftern those lines above I have further patterns detailing the source folders to copy stuff from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the order of the patterns was the issue. Moving the exclude patterns from the question after the include patterns telling the folders to copy from fixed my issue, and now source files are correctly not being copied over.

I could not find this information in the documentation, and it does not appear obvious to me that this should be the behaviour.

I hope this helps someone.